# Make Up/Down arrow in input boxes not do anything

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

How can I make `<input>` elements not react to pressing the <kbd>Up</kbd> arrow (keyCode 38) or the <kbd>Down</kbd> arrow (keyCode 40), while they are focused? I'm using jQuery for the project, but have no qualms against writing it in raw JS if that's easier.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like this:

```
$('.yourinputclass').keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 38 or e.which == 40) return false; // or you can use e.preventDefault(); like it was mentioned in the comments
});
```

Documentation [here](http://api.jquery.com/event.which/)

Comment: or use [preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) instead of return false